# serializing a Django ModelSerializer into json?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have defined a model with a property I'd like to be included in the serialization:

```
class Flower(models.Model):
    health = CharField(...)

    @property
    def is_okay(self):
        return self.health == 'ok'

class OKSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_okay = serializers.Field()

    class Meta:
        model = Flower
        fields = '__all__'
```

Originally I was using the `django.core.serializers` to serialize into `json`:

```
flowers = Flower.objects.all()
serialized_flowers = serializers.serialize("json", flowers)
```

Which was super nice, but Django does not serialize the custom property on the model, so I had to create my own serializer like you see above. However, when I try to do the same, I get an error:

```
serialized_flowers = OKSerializer.serialize("json", flowers)

# ERROR" 'OKSerializer' has no attribute 'serialize'
```

This is probably because I'm using `ModelSerializer`, which has no `serialize()` function.

Is there a way I can serialize into `json` using `ModelSerializer` like I had done before? Does `ModelSerializer` have a function for serializing into json?

---

**EDIT**
I also tried:

```
serialized_flowers = OKSerializer("json", flowers)
```

But when I try to `print(serialized_flowers)` or even returning it as `HttpResponse(serialized_flowers, content_type='application/json')`, it results in the following error:

```
AssertionError: When a serializer is passed a `data` keyword argument you must call `.is_valid()` before attempting to access the serialized `.data` representation.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class OKSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 is_okay = serializers.SerializerMethodField('is_okay')
 class Meta:
  model = models.Flower
  fields = ['health', 'is_okay']

 def is_okay(self, flower):
  flower = flower.health
  return flower == 'ok'
```

change your serializer to this
and delete @property from modal

Comment: This results in the error `AssertionError: When a serializer is passed a 'data' keyword argument you must call '.is_valid()' before attempting to access the serialized '.data' representation.` when I try to `print(serialized_flowers)`

Comment: don't put "json" in the arguments of the serializers **serialized_flowers = OKSerializer(flowers)**

Comment: If I don't include the `json` part, then I get the error `The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the 'QuerySet' instance.`.  But this is confusing because in my model you can see `is_okay` as a Model property, and on the OKSerializer it is a serializer Field. Also how would the serializer know to output `json` if I don't specify it?

Comment: you can use an alternative serializerMethod field delete @property from model an `def is_okay(self, Flower)  flower = Flower.health return flower == 'ok' ` and write it as a method in serializer class and make is_okay **serializerMethod field** , serializer work is to convert data to json we don't need to tell it about format

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#readonlyfield